# Detect all devices connected to my wifi modem -Android

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-networking, wifimanager, wifip2p

I have researched quiet a bit on the topic and seen similar questions on stackoverflow and have explored **WifiManager** and **Wifi-peer to peer** classes.
Also I have decompiled some apk's which seem to be giving result's similar to what i want and they seem to be doing something with WifiManager but i am unable to pick the required logic from it as they have a lot of files ( mostly irrelevant ) once decompiled.

I have also used the "**Android Network Discovery**" library but i am  Unable to get Host Vendors name and DeviceType from it. 
A direction on how I can proceed with this is well appreciated.

Thank you.!